# How to make CSS background-position with negative left value visible?

Tags: css, background-image, background-position, negative-number

I have a `<ul>` element with `list-style:none;` and `<li>` with `padding:20px;` and `background-image:url(images/bullet.gif) no-repeat -20px 10px;`.

The bullet is not visible.
The workaround I'm using now is 0 instead -20px for the background-position and for the `<li>` element `position:relative;padding-left:20px;margin-left:-20px;`.

Is there a better way of doing this?

**EDIT:** I need the bullet to be outside of the `<ul>` box. This being the reason for using negative margin.

Thank you.

Comment: Nop - that is perfectly ok to do.

Comment: @Francisc what about `list-style-image: url(images/bullet.gif);` ?

Comment: I want to position the `<li>` starting position to be vertically aligned with something else and it doesn't work consistently with all browsers when I set `list-style:outside;`.

Comment: My fix would be to use the method that you are currently using. Definitely your best way of going about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/sC8BR/2/

Comment: But if you set padding to 20 and then margin to -20 the visible area for the bullet is outside of your vision. Not only that, but you set the background 20 pixel more to the left of the beggining the <li>. Try the example that i've putt in my answer.

Comment: I need the bullet to be outside of the `<ul>` box.

Comment: OK, it looks like what I said I was using.

Comment: yes? I thought your problem was bullets that are not visibles.

Comment: They are not visible when using negative values for background-position. The solution I said I was using is exactly like what you wrote in your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a jsfiddle example. http://jsfiddle.net/jesseatkinson/z2qss/.
Your CSS should look like this.

```
ul li {
    background: url(../bullet.gif) left center no-repeat transparent;
    padding-left: 40px;
    list-style: none; 
}
```

Comment: I need the bullet to be outside of the `<ul>` box.

Comment: I'm confused? What do you mean. Just increase the padding... Can you proved the HTML that you're working with? A clearer example of your goals?

Comment: I want to have a negative left value for the background-position and have the background image show.